# Automate taking screenshots of the same region on the screen

Tags: windows-7, automation, screenshot

I am looking for a way to be able to automate to take the screenshot of the same region on the screen. That is, when I click, it should take the screenshot of a specific region on the screen. (Windows 7 64 Bit)

Comment: Does it need to be a click? How about a key combination? HyperSnap allows you to capture a fixed area repeatedly after the first manual capture. So you'd need to make one capture, then you can set the program to always make a capture of the same region whenever you use the key combo. It's a good, solid, shareware package that's been around more than 20 years and the author actively supports the product and participates in the user forum on the site. Hyperonics: https://www.hyperionics.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could, assuming that the area of the screen that you need to screenshot is fixed, create an icon or shortcut for [imagemagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/) such as `magick convert screenshot: -crop 200x200+100+300 screenshot.png`